# IE8 regexp finding newline characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript regexp to replace newline characters with html paragraphs. In FireFox, Safari and Chrome I have no problem, but in IE8 it fails to find any newline characters at all. I have tried both `/\n/g` and `/\r\n/` but without success. Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: have you tried the unicode characters?

Comment: I've tried using /\u000A/ but still without success.

Comment: I've also tried /\u000D/\u000A/ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Some things you could try:

```
/[\012\015]+/
/[\x0A\x0D]+/
/[\r\n]+/
/(\012|\015)+/
/(\x0A|\x0D)+/
/(\r|\n)+/
```

Comment: `/[\r\n]+/` is priceless. Thank you.